# R error: subscript out of bounds (updated)

Tags: r, r-caret

Updated to be more specific with the problem.  I am working with a 31x3 matrix.  Dput() output below.

Calling data:

```
x <- Macro[1:31,3:4]
x <- as.matrix(x)
x
y <- Macro[1:31,2:2]
y <- as.matrix(y)
y
```

Specify traincontrol:

```
ctrl2 = trainControl(
  method = "cv", 
  number = 2,
  verboseIter = TRUE
 )
```

Fit to lm:

```
myfit <- caret::train(y ~ ., 
                  data = x,
                  method = "lm", 
                  trControl = ctrl2)
```

The error from running the above code is returned below.  Any idea how to fix?

```
+ Fold1: intercept=TRUE 
- Fold1: intercept=TRUE 
+ Fold2: intercept=TRUE 
- Fold2: intercept=TRUE 
Aggregating results
Fitting final model on full training set
Error in data[, all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
```

Dput:

```
 dput(x)
structure(c(0.615707773, 1.243711825, 1.101635544, 1.168158763, 
1.217570671, 1.61196623, 1.175834585, 1.212395636, 1.364939572, 
1.568682833, 1.492714256, 1.548748565, 1.587380088, 2.500917187, 
2.411769733, 2.209745562, 2.181714652, 2.702684603, 2.151281502, 
2.311959904, 2.021725337, 2.811498353, 2.25549484, 2.312197702, 
2.371454247, 2.929109631, 2.436780195, 2.37055423, 2.2516274, 
2.9347511, 2.594177614, 0.00955776, 1.124040765, 1.388953574, 
1.442220109, 1.278039696, 1.492471349, 1.241292358, 1.219318408, 
1.106157588, 1.425821283, 1.492232414, 1.297264094, 1.290573552, 
1.693672926, 1.615503841, 1.416672157, 1.495830759, 1.909516723, 
1.578722765, 1.810574654, 1.460086293, 2.063870658, 1.573873402, 
1.875213097, 1.822404408, 2.210370183, 2.00485323, 1.737927831, 
1.893701997, 2.512806555, 2.286457171), .Dim = c(31L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
    "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
    "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"
    ), c("c1372", "c5244")))


    dput(y)
structure(c(1270.13, 1898.063, 1479.839, 1464.988, 1327.572, 
1957.292, 1460.983, 1457.527, 1329.201, 2015.304, 1549.553, 1520.144, 
1408.813, 2969.499, 2347.697, 2289.456, 2237.209, 3038.233, 2370.037, 
2295.203, 2033.545, 2979.778, 2256.155, 2248.855, 2082.9, 2890.8, 
2263.7, 2182.23, 2037, 2873.85, 2326.65), .Dim = c(31L, 1L))
```

Comment: I used as.data.frame.matrix to convert both x and y.  The same code now returns the error: Error in model.frame.default(form = y ~ ., data = x, na.action = na.fail) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'y'

Comment: Try `myfit <- caret::train(y = as.vector(y), x = x, method = "lm", trControl = ctrl2)`.

Comment: Thanks @markus.  The error that returns from your code is: Error in train.default(y = as.vector(y), x = as.vector(x), method = "lm",  : 
  wrong model type for classification

Comment: Worked for me. Don't do `x = as.vector(x)`, just  `x = x`.

Comment: @markus - thanks so much!  Out of curiosity, any idea why this step was necessary?

Comment: @ZJAY Glad it worked. `y`is supposed to be a vector, see `?caret::train`